# Controling ports on localhost

Tags: http, tcp, localhost, port, netcat

i am trying to learn socket programming with PHP but quickly ran into binding errors on ports,now my attention is diverted onto solving port issues, how do i go about fully controlling ports on my machine, what commands do i use?

```
sudo netcat -z -vv localhost http
localhost [127.0.0.1] 80 (http): Connection refused
```

my problem is i get connection refused on port 80
and when i run a port scan on my iMac i only get

```
netcat -v -z -n -w 1 127.0.0.1 1-1023
127.0.0.1 88 (kerberos) open
127.0.0.1 548 (afpovertcp) open
127.0.0.1 631 (ipp) open
```

how do i add port 80 (http) open
to that list?

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: You need a webserver (or another server listening to tcp80) to accept incoming traffic on the port. This is more of a SuperUser og ServerFault question as it is not related to a specific programming or scripting-problem.